# What does the att assembly operation [sub (%eax), edx] actually do?

Tags: assembly, gdb, att

I am working in disassembling a program in c using gdb and the at&t assembly shows the following.

```
sub    (%eax),%edx
mov    %edx,(%eax)
add    $0x4,%eax
```

I am not exactly sure how the subtraction is working here. As I interpret it, the value in %edx will have the memory location of %eax subtracted from it. A.k.a %edx = %edx - (%eax). The values I get when printing the register values after this happens are odd and I am not sure what it is exactly doing. Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

eax is being used as an pointer to a 4 byte integer (could be unsigned). The c equivalent would be:

```
edx -= *eax;
*eax = edx;
eax++;
```